# How to write junit test cases for catch block of DAO layer to achieve better code coverage?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

I am writing junit test cases for my spring boot application and have to achieve 90% code coverage.
I want to cover catch block coverage also so I tried test case for catch block of DAO layer method but its not working as expected.

below code is DAO layer code

```
public class GeneratorRepository {



    @Value("${existingQuery}")
    private String existingQuery;

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private BeanPropertyRowMapper<Generator> generatorRowMapper;


    public Generator findExisting(Request request) {
        Generator ut = new Generator();
        try {
            SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("no", request.getId(), Types.VARCHAR)
                    .addValue("trSu", request.getSu(), Types.VARCHAR)
                    .addValue("sta", request.getSta(), Types.VARCHAR);
            uti = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(existingQuery, namedParameters, generatorRowMapper);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            uti = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return ut;
    }

}
```

my test case
this test case it not covering catch block.

```
@Test
    public void findExistingException() {
        Request request = new Request("12365", "QW" "qw");
        
        when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(ArgumentMatchers.<String>any(), any(SqlParameterSource.class), eq(generatorRowMapper))).thenReturn(null);
        
        when(generatorRepo.findExisting(request)).thenThrow(new EmptyResultDataAccessException(1));
        EmptyResultDataAccessException exception = assertThrows(EmptyResultDataAccessException.class, () -> generatorRepo.findExisting(request));
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't throw an exception -- the exception is caught.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to mock the `queryForObject` method call and make it throw the desired exception. After that, you can assert that the `Generator` returned is null (because, in this case, you are assigning the value: `uti = null;` and later returning it):

```
@Test
public void findExistingException() {
    // given
    when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(any(), any(), any()).thenThrow(new EmptyResultDataAccessException(1));
    // when
    Generator result = generatorRepo.findExisting(new Request("12365", "QW" "qw"));
    // then
    assertThat(result).isNull();
}
```